# How to make ALT+TAB with Gnome-Do's Docky work?

Tags: 10.04, gnome, docky, workspaces

I would like to use Gnome-Do's Docky but it requires me to enable either

- visual effects in the Appearances
  preferences (change from None to
  Normal) which I think enables compiz OR
- metacity's compositing_manager option in gconf-editor

The problem is that when I change my visual effects from None to Normal, I can no longer drag and drop a window to another workspace using the workspace switcher applet. From what I've read, this is a compiz bug that hasn't been fixed for years.

On the other hand, the problem with using metacity's compositing_manager is that my <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> becomes noticeably slower than the usual.

Is there a way to make things work? Since it seems that the compiz problem is not going to be fixed, I wonder if there's a way to fix my alt+tab with metacity's compositing enabled.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the metacity problem is going no where. Metacity has become mutter, for the most part, and the compiz bug is less of a bug in compiz and more of a bug in the gnome-panel. I don't think you will be able to get a solution to either (any time soon).